# using Objective-C protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a protocol defined in Objective-C as below

```
@protocol TestProtocol

@required
- (void) printInputString:(NSString*) s

@end
```

This protocol is shipped to Swift project via pod and the module name is `someModule`

I want to use this protocol in Swift projects on

> 1. Pure Swift Class, i.e. not getting inherited from NSObject
> 2. Swift class that gets inherited from NSObject (for e.g. via UIViewController)

Example 1.

```
class TestPureSwiftClass: TestProtocol
```

Example 2.

```
class ArgumentModificationSwift: UIViewController, TestProtocol
```

When I do implement only for `Example 1` everything works fine, but as soon as I do it as in `Example 2` - it gives me error `Module someModule not found`

How to fix this?

Comment: I see `TestProtocol` and I'm wondering: was this a unit test target (where `UIViewController` might not exist)?